# Safari - workaround for triggering pop-up from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, safari

A website has the following structure:

[image]

The user clicks on a button on the parent page and a script sends a message to the iframe instructing it to do the popup action.

It works for all browsers except Safari.
Also, it works in Safari once the popup blocker feature is turned off.
Are there any workarounds for this to work?

Comment: Can you show a working (malfunctioning) example? Also it looks like the popup blocker is working as it should, and blocking the popup.

Comment: I'm not seeing any buttons? https://i.imgur.com/478KkX6.png A minimal working example in for example codepen or jsbin is always the easiest way to help.

Comment: oops sorry. I'll get back to you on this later.